# Scheme vector-fold and vector-map analog in Clojure?

Tags: vector, clojure, scheme

How can I make in Clojure functions vector-fold and vector-map from scheme?

Comment: Are you looking for `reduce` and `map`?

Comment: Clojure defines its fold (`reduce`) and map (`map`) operations in terms of the [sequence abstraction](https://clojure.org/reference/sequences). There is no need for special versions for different data structures.

Comment: @akond And Can you please ask what about vector-cumulate function?

Comment: @APatrikMs94 it is `reductions`

Comment: @akond sorry for disturbing you, but can you please ask what about begin function?

Comment: `begin` in scheme is equivalent to `do` in clojure.

Answer (score 4):

To map over a vector and get a vector back you can use `mapv`.
To fold over a vector you can use regular `reduce` since vectors are seqable.
To get an index in the function you're iterating with, there's `map-indexed` or you can use `(range)`:

```
(mapv (fn [i e] [i e]) [1 2 3] (range))
=> [[1 0] [2 1] [3 2]]
```